# Trying to install 15.10 on a Laptop

Tags: partitioning, software-installation, windows-7, 15.10, gateway

I have a Gateway laptop that runs Ubuntu 14.04 from a external hard drive(long story). I am trying to install 15.10 from a usb drive to the windows 7 partition on the laptop so I can do away with the hard drive. I made the boot usb with the 15.10 iso and booted it, but when I go to erase and encrypt the disk it aborts and restarts. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Boot into the windows 7 partition and start setup from within windows then choose the "alongside windows" option

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's difficult to say what you are doing wrong if you don't show any of your actual commands and none of the results (i.e. error messages). I assume that you don't want to keep the Windows 7 partition.

- The USB method

  To **boot from USB** used to be a challenge to say the least. More recent PC's are generally capable of USB boot. But if the Laptop is slightly older, that might be an issue. I'd try to avoid it if possible. Second problem: **encryption**. If it boots ok and the problems start with the encryption, then **don't select encryption**. It is easier to reinstall with encryption later if you have already "excercised" the "normal" install. It is also simpler to add an encrypted home partition later if you need one.
- Why don't you try a simple ***format and copy*** method, since you seem to have a working Ubuntu 14.04 (although an external drive)? This is a bit a "risky" operation, but if you already have some experience with ubuntu/linux it may be a good alternative. (I've done it this way a couple of times) If you anyway don't want to keep the Windows partition, then your not risking anything (except some spare time).

You need to do most of these commands as `root`. If you don't understand the commands well enough, I'd suggest that you read up on them first.

1. start the Laptop from the external drive
2. partition the internal drive. (replace `sda` with your *actual* drive. I'm assuming `sda0` here)

   ```
       fdisk /dev/sda
   ```

   If you prefer this with a graphical interface you can use `gparted`. If it's not installed you can install it with `sudo apt-get install gparted`. I suggest you create one "normal" partition as `ext4` and a `swap` partition. Mark the "normal" partition as "bootable".
3. create a filesystem on your "normal" partition

   ```
       mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda0
   ```
4. mount the newly created partition (here to `/mnt/new`)

   ```
       mkdir /mnt/new
       mount -t ext4 -o rw /dev/sda0 /mnt/new
   ```
5. copy the complete externa harddrive (here assumed to be `/`) to the internal drive recursively (so all files and subdirectories are copied)

   ```
       cp -R / /mnt/new
   ```

   Depending on the size of the external harddrive, this may take some time. The directories `dev` `proc` and `sys` are not required, and can be deleted afterwards.
6. install grub on the internal drive

   ```
       grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/new/boot /dev/sda
   ```
7. edit the file `/mnt/new/etc/fstab`

   This file needs to contain the correct configuration of your actual drives. Since you copied it from the external drive, it still contains the paths to the external drive. These need to be changed to the internal drive.
8. reboot

Comment: Okay so the reason for the external hard drive is a couple years ago i got a rootkit on my gateway w7 laptop. Me being a novice and exhausting all of my efforts asked my not nice cousin who works with computers what to do. He tells me to install linux on a flash drive( I assumed i could just delete the hard drive when I was done) and it could fix it. Somehow i screwed my Win7 boot up and was left clueless running Ubuntu on a ehd. So i adapted and got used to it and eventually fixed the Win7 boot but for some reason i was missing a wifi driver and could not connect to anything.

Comment: But it would still connect in Ubuntu so I blew it off again. I realized I am a few distros behind and went to upgrade and then learned 14.10 and 15.04 are dead. So a fresh install of 15.10 would be my best option. It would  be a pain and make no sense to do it on my ehd when i could kill two birds with one stone and put it on my 300 gig unused win7 internal drive. So i downloaded a 15.10 64 bit Iso from Qbittorrent, Used startup disk creator to install it to a 8 gb flash drive. Deleted the win7 partition on /dev/sda with Gparted so its unallocated

Comment: If I have a Intel Pentium P6100 processor should I have used the 64-bit amd or the 32-bit i386 version, It's 64-bit but its Intel?

Comment: @mrtuttle: I would nowadays always suggest to go with 64-bit (Windows or Linux or any other system). As this is the direction the is moving. But technically, you **can** install a 32-bit system. On Linux you'll not loose a lot (on windows that's a bit different).